# Eclipse syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to Eclispe. I just met a problem. I copy a piece code from a website into the Eclipse. the IDE editor prompt that: Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

I am sure that my code is OK. If I manually input the code, it's ok. I open the java file from Notepad++. I found there are some blank spaces(green highlighted). If I remove the green highlighted blanks, the Eclipse errors is gone.

I post some images. I googled for a while, but I didn't find useful information, so I seek help here.

What are those blank spaces? How to eliminate the error when copying?
Why does this happen?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Those are probably non-breaking spaces. How do you avoid them when copying code blindly from the web? Well, don't do that. Or delete the problematic white spaces.

Comment: you may try to paste-copy your text to notepad and then copy code into eclipse, it helps me. but its temporary solution, only for small files.

Answer (score 2):

Please remove red space, and press Tab again.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid copy pasting code from any other place. Type in the code by yourself, it will help because the problem of non-breaking spaces will not occur.

Answer (score 2):

Just cut the code from eclipse save the file and then open compose gmail and paste it and copy same come back to eclipse and paste and save the file.

Answer (score 1):

all the problematic spaces can be quickly removed using the Find/Replace dialog, select one of the red spaces then insert a normal space in the "Replace with" textfield and finally "Replace All"